# How to parse date string?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, date, nsdateformatter

I have to parse date like these:

```
Thu, 09 Apr 2015 11:31:14 GMT  
Tue, 05 May 2015 15:06:37 GMT  
Tue, 09 Dec 2014 08:28:19 GMT
```

I'm using `NSDateFormatter`.
I tried `@"E, d M y H:m:s Z"` and `@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"` and many other but **it doesn't work.**
Can you help me?

```
NSString *dataStr=@"Tue, 09 Dec 2014 08:28:19 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"E, d M y H:m:s Z"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:dataStr];
NSLog(@"Date: %@  Converted: %@",dataStr, dte);
```

I do not have any error when compiling but my NSLog output is:

```
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 08:28:19 GMT Converted: (null)
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @HotLicks: parsing dates implies the desired behavior, the shortest code is included. only a sufficient error description is missing.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @thelaws: the formats are correct.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - For all we know it doesn't compile, or it throws an `unrecognized selector`.

Comment: @HotLicks it returns nil. simple as that.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Where does the OP say that?????????????????

Comment: He doesn't. I just wanted to point out, that 2 of 3 things you name missing, are there.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact, that your current locale probably doesn't fit. Set it to `en_US_POSIX`

```
for (NSString* dataStr in @[@"Thu, 09 Apr 2015 11:31:14 GMT",@"Tue, 05 May 2015 15:06:37 GMT", @"Tue, 09 Dec 2014 08:28:19 GMT"]){

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"E, d M y H:m:s Z"];
    NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:dataStr];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@  Converted: %@",dataStr, dte);
}
```

returns

```
Date: Tue, 05 May 2015 15:06:37 GMT  Converted: 2015-05-05 15:06:37 +0000 
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 11:31:14 GMT  Converted: 2015-04-09 11:31:14 +0000
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 08:28:19 GMT  Converted: 2014-12-09 08:28:19 +0000
```

more information [Technical Q&A QA1480: NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Problem Solved**.

The matter was just an hidden character ( newline = \n ) in the original date string coming from an XML RSS.
I solved it replacing the hidden character with a null string.

```
dataStr = [dataStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Thank for your help.